# Is there a time function to record the amount of time it takes a part of a method to do a job?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, time, fibonacci

I have an assignment in which I'm required to have  a Fibonacci Seq in recursion, simple enough for me, but I also need to record the time it took each step to solve or start and finish one step. Say my n is 20, then 20 iterations of the Fibonacci sequence will be show, but I need how much time each n or output took. I used :

```
long start=System.nanoTime();
long end= System.nanoTime();
long dif=end-start;
System.out.println("time taken was " + dif);
```

In the my method as someone had posted before but I had some issues in which the output was flooded with the time and then the last n output which is not what I need.

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
class ProjectRecur {

    public static void main (String args[]){    
        System.out.println("Enter the Integer  for n.");

        int numm= new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        System.out.println("You have choosen the n to be : "+ numm);

        for(int i =1; i<= numm; i++){                   
            System.out.println(Recursion(i)+ "" );      
        }
    }

    public static long Recursion(int numm){    
        if(numm ==1||numm ==2){             
            return 1;
        }
        // this line below is Fn=Fn-1+Fn-2
        return Recursion(numm-1)+Recursion(numm-2);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Can you clearly phrase your question please? For good answers we need good questions! :)

Comment: how did you use the timing in your code, please show them in real use